# Como verificar se o json é um objeto

Tags: php

Bom recebe um json na minha página assim:

```
// Decodifica o Json
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

echo $obj->Autenticacao[0]->login;
```

O Json que esta sendo enviado esta assim:

```
{
"Autenticacao": [{
    "login": "root",
    "senha": "123"
}]
}
```

Tudo funciona 100%, porém quem removo as [] do json, o php me informa o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Como identificar se o json completo.

Comment: Se não tiver `[]` deixa de ser possível fazer `Autenticacao[0]`, teria que ser só `$obj->Autenticacao->login`. [is_object](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-object.php) consegue verificar se determinado campo é um objeto e [is_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-array.php) para ver se é array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então se **não** pretendes um array na propriedade **Autenticacao**, **Não** podes fazer isto:

```
echo $obj->Autenticacao[0]->login;
```

Porque estas a tentar acessar em forma de *array* que não existe deveria ser da seguinte maneira:

```
echo $obj->Autenticacao->login;
```

E para acessares dessa maneira o teu json deve ser algo parecido com:

```
{
    "Autenticacao": {
        "login": "root",
        "senha": "123"
    }
}
```